# how to add css file to mvc4

Tags: css, layout, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a css file that I want to put in my layout.
in the web.config file I wrote:

```
<location path="App_themes/default.css">
          <system.web>
             <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/>
             </authorization>
          </system.web>
       </location>
```

and in the layout.cshtml I wrote:

```
 <style>
        h2 {
            color:red;
        }

          @Styles.Render("~/App_themes/css")  

    </style>
```

but it doesn't recognize the line: @styles.render
what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

See [Styles.Render in MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028401/styles-render-in-mvc4).

You need to read-up on Bundling and Minification to get a clear picture of what is going on, but one thing is for certain the `@Styles.Render("~/App_Themes/css")` call should be done outside of the context of the `<style/>` tag.

```
@Styles.Render("~/App_Themes/css")
<style> h2 { color: red; } </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

pleas run project in iis
project / right Click/ properties/ web/ use local IIS web server

Answer (score 0):

Put `@Styles.Render("~/App_Themes/css")` inside the head element on your layout page (`_Layout.cshtml`)

Put the style `h2 { color: red; }` in your style sheet that lives in `theApp_Themes/css` subfolder.