# Applying CSS to an layout page in MVC

Tags: css, razor, model-view-controller

I'm new to ASP core MVC,
Im trying to create a nav section.
I created the following path to my CSS: Content/CSS/stylesheet.
I dragged the sheet (with some simple css) into the head of the _Layout page.
When I load up the page using the layout template, no css to be found.

This is purely just learning MVC.

The layout folder is Views/Shared/_Layout.

Ive tried different paths
Ive tried different css

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="~/Content/CSS/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" /> //This wont work
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

</head>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styles.Render in MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028401/styles-render-in-mvc4)

Comment: Make sure that the build action property of the stylesheet.css file in your solution is set to `Content`.

Comment: Martin D, It indeed seems to be set to content,
Right click on css file-properties-Build Action = Content